# Hosting a Facebook Messenger bot in github pages

Tags: node.js, facebook, github, bots, github-pages

Is it possible to host a Facebook Messenger bot made using nodejs on a website on github pages?

If yes what are the steps I have to take to configure my bot to run on github pages? 
If no then are there any free hosting solutions with https where this is possible?

Currently I run my bot by exposing my localhost to the internet using ngrok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub Pages is a static website hosting service; it sounds like you'll need a dynamic hosting service.

You can check out [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps) or [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com) among many other options. Both Heroku and AWS offer free hosting with limitations. AWS has the free tier available for the first year; Heroku has one free Dyno allotted per month.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those.